# Don't render html when scraping content with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm working on a scraper to collect contact information for a marketing project, but I'm running into an issue with trying to organize the scraped data within my script. One of the biggest issues I'm running into is as follows:

```
<font attribute="something">

   <font otherattribute="somethingelse">

      <font otherattribute="onemore">

         Content of Interest

      </font>
   </font>
</font>
```

When trying to parse the DOM and scrape out the content of interest, my script looks for `<font>` within another `<font>` and saves all content it finds to an array as unique entries. The issue, however, is that I'm finding repeat entries within the array. I tried having the script check for quality between two successive entries before pushing them into the array, but I get results like the following when `var_dump()` is called on two entries that APPEAR equal, but are not considered equal by the script.

```
string(76) "Content of Interest" 
string(47) "Content of Interest"
```

My best guess is that the PHP script is rendering the HTML rather then treating each entry as the `innertext` of the HTML node. I want to only save a simple text version of the content pulled from each node.

**How can I ensure that the string saved to the array is ONLY the text that I can see? Not rendered HTML, which contains parts that I can't see in my browser?**

Comment: Can you show us how you're trying to parse the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php functions like strip_tags() to receive your text without any HTML.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: You, sir or madam, are a PHP wizard. I didn't even know this function existed. Thank God for stackoverflow.